# Получение счетов жкх через api госуслуг или гис ЖКХ

Tags: госуслуги

коллеги. Хочу получить сведения и неоплаченных счетах жкх отдельных лиц через oauth2 (желательно счета в виде pdf). Ближайшее, что вижу это методы этого сервиса гис жкх
http://open-gkh.ru/BillsServiceAsync/

Но метод exportPaymentDocumentData не говорит о том, оплачен счёт или нет и не говорит о размере задолженности. Как я могу это установить? Искал в api госуслуг, но тоже не нашёл. Что я упускаю?